# Python: Adding Fields to Objects Dynamically

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I am wondering whether it is possible to add fields to objects dynamically. For example, I want to be able to add something like:

```
user = object()
user.first_name = 'John'
user.last_name = 'Smith'
```

When I execute that in Python command line interpretor I get:

```
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Object:
    pass

obj = Object()
obj.x = 5
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I have two questions 1) What does the 'pass' keyword mean here? 2) If I have another instance obj2 of Object() in my code, will obj.x create obj2.x (with some undefined value)?

Comment: 1) Regarding `pass`: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements 2) No, when you do `obj.x = 5`, you only add `x` attribute to single instance of `Object`. If you want all `Object` instances to share x, you have to do `Object.x = 5`.

Comment: There is no such thing as an undefined value in Python - the closest it gets is `None`. Objects created in the way gruszczy proposes do not have any kind of "prototype"; you can add and delete attributes at will, and it has no effect on any other instance of the Object class.

Comment: Nice simple way to fake up an object with an attribute, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You cannot assign to attributes of `object` instances like this. Derive from `object`, and use an instance of that class.